# Failing to chisel (boolean difference) text on a cube side

Tags: modifiers, text-object

I'm trying to create a gravestone with chiseled text on it.

I have a cube (the stone) a text for which I added some depth and bevel, and then converted to a mesh.

I positioned the text so that it's partly "inside" the cube and tried adding a boolean difference modifier on the cube (cube - text), so that the text would be chiseled in the stone.

This gets Blender crazy. Initially nothing worked. I used a decimate modifier on the text to reduce its complexity, and now A few letters are chiseled, the rest are not.

This is how things look when Both the cube (headstone) and the text (now a mesh) are visible (there's another grave base object, but we can ignore it):

[image: Both gravestone and text shown]

The gravestone has the boolean difference modifier, and if I hide the text, this is what I see:

[image: Gravestone with some chiseling]

What can I do to make this work? I don't actually need to render this scene, I want to
convert it to an STL file and 3D print it.

**More info**: As stated in the comments, this is due to the text being non-manifold. Actually, it has 2000+ non-manifold edges!

If I try to remove doubles, it just deletes the entire text. No matter what the double threshold is (tried 1mm, 0.1mm, etc. - I'm working with metric units).

Any suggestions on this?

**The file with the issue** can be found at: [this location](https://sites.google.com/site/blender3dtopics/files/gravestone.blend?attredirects=0&d=1)

**Another file** can be found at: [this location](https://sites.google.com/site/blender3dtopics/files/rip-remesh.blend?attredirects=0&d=1).
This time, I've used the remesh modifier, but it only worked for one text object (converted to a mesh and remeshed), not the other two. The difference between the one that works, and the others that don't is that for the first one I used Octree depth = 7, and for the other two I used Octree depth = 8 (as 7 wasn't smooth enough).
To test this, just replace the object used in the boolean modifier of the cute from 'RIP' (which works) to either 'iGoogle' or 'years', which don't work.

Comment: Most likely it's because the text is non-manifold. Try selecting the text in edit mode and pressing W > Remove doubles.

Comment: Also, make sure all you normals are correct(Edit mode > Select Everything(A) > Ctrl - N).

Comment: Boolean operations will sometimes fail if one of the objects is super low poly.  You could try sub-dividing the head-stone once or twice.

Comment: Hm.. Is it possible you could you upload your .blend?

Comment: for this specific requirement I would be using a displacement modifier with a bitmap. It works like a bump map but creates/modifies real geometry.

Comment: You might want to try [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=AG9pz1hMEXQ#t=0s) workflow. Your mesh contains T-Junctions and is as @gandalf3 stated not manifold and self-intersecting.

Answer (score 5):

Try adding a remesh modifier to the text:

[image]

Then the boolean modifier will work as expected:

[image]

Comment: This definitely works. The end result still fails the manifold test in the 3D printing tools, but the result STL can be sliced for 3D printing (tried slic3r).

Comment: The solution seems to only work for the word 'RIP' ;-)
Tried another example with 3 text objects, but only one worked. Uploaded the file. Thanks for the great help so far.

Comment: The normals are off on the other text objects, but Ctrl+N won't work because for some reason they are still non-manifold..

Answer (score 1):

Correct the normals of your text.
Select the text, enter the Edit Mode, Select Everything <kbd>A</kbd>, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>, then go back to object mode.

Comment: You know how stack exchange works, but yet you used an answer to try to @reply to two other users. You must know the @ ping system does not work in answers, and answer should not be used as comments.