# Engraving went Wrong

Tags: modifiers, text-object

[image: Engraving gone wrong]

I dont know what happened the rest worked well but the main one didnt and its has done this weird glitch sort of thing.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75728/how-to-fix-imported-svg-from-inkscape-with-wrong-fill/ and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65555/importing-a-good-mesh/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extrude and bevel an imported svg curve](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47217/extrude-and-bevel-an-imported-svg-curve)

Comment: Be aware the that a Text/Font extruded and converted to a Mesh is non-manifold and can cause these sort of Boolean issues. Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15963/failing-to-chisel-boolean-difference-text-on-a-cube-side

Comment: You can try doing that with an image instead of a text/curve. Text generates irregular and problematic topology. I would suggest that you do it this with an image and displacement, or bump or both. Read: [how to create a business card with an embossed effect](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/109605/how-to-create-a-buisness-card-with-an-embossed-effect/109644#109644)